# Multi Threading in Java for Audio

Tags: java, multithreading, audio

I finally figured out how to play audio with java, and enjoyed the implications of it; however, when I wanted to create a music selecting program, one that would include functioning buttons, I realized that my methods of playing the audio would conflict with the rest of the program. When playing the audio, I need to use a Thread.sleep that will last the same length as the audio file, but that prevents me from pausing, choosing a different song, etc. I have not fully completed the main part of my program, as I just started today. I have searched some different websites about multi threading and playing audio in Java, yet none give me a good method of resolving this issue. I wanted to know if it's possible to create a new thread, and then run audio on it at the same time as the original thread, and how I would access one from the other. Thanks

P.S. Ik this is confusing as frick if clarification and pictures r needed ill send them as needed

Comment: *"I have searched some different websites about multi threading and playing audio in Java, yet none give me a good method of resolving this issue."*, I doubt that you've done any serious research then. E.g. have a look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm) or [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-in-java/); there are many more resources. Please consider putting some hours into understanding multithreading rather than searching for a quick-fix like solution.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I've only had 5 months of practice and this is my first project.
I'm already on one of the links that you sent me, and it didn't help me understand how to run the audio file on the new thread. Again, I just started this today, and I've never tinkered with Threads except for Thread.sleep

Comment: What don't you understand there? Both links are clearly explaining how to use threads including how to start one. Please narrow down your question to a *specific* problem. Please add the relevant code to the question as well. In the current state it's unfortunately too general and cannot be answered properly.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.sleep` is only used with audio in situation where it is necessary to keep the program from exiting while the audio is playing. If your program is running, doing other things for the duration, there is no need for the sleep command.

When you play a `Clip` or `SourceDataLine`, the audio rendering that is called runs on its own thread, but the thread is a `daemon` thread. A daemon thread, unlike regular threads, will not hold a running Java program open.

I haven't seen the rest of your code, but a good way to demonstrate this to yourself would be to create a simple form with a button. Have the button launch the sound and DON'T include any sleep commands. As long as the form with the button is up and visible, the sound should play through to completion.